# How to determinate maximum (integer) fd number returned by _open_osfhandle()?

Tags: winapi

Does Win32 have an API (e.g. POSIX has `getconf()`/`pathconf()`) to determinate the maximum fd (integer) value which `_open_osfhandle()`/`_open()` can return?

Documentation for `semaxstdio()` (which is for `fopen()`&co, not for `_open()`!!) at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmaxstdio?view=msvc-170 says:

> ... C run-time I/O now supports up to 8,192 files open simultaneously at the low I/O level ...

But, how can I get that value at runtime (or compile-time)?

P.S.: The value is used to scale the size of internal tables of other libraries (for which we do not have the sources), so the only options are to use "8192" hardcoded, or a systems real limit obtained via an API

Comment: FYI, the correct way to format inline code in StackOverflow markup is to use `\`...\`` instead of `|...|`. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Is there a reason why knowing this would be useful? A call to `CreateFileW` can fail for any number of reasons, so you'll need to implement error handling anyway. That error handling doesn't look different whether you know the maximum number of concurrent file system object handles or not.

Comment: @llnspectable The code uses _open_osfhandle() and _open(), which return a POSIX-style fd, represented by an integer (see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html).

I am not going to change a 9600000+ line codebase, I just want to define the (safety) limits. I could hardcode |8192|, but I would prefer a getconf()-style API or header file to get the limit.

Comment: That doesn't explain why knowing the maximum value ahead of time were useful. [`_open_osfhandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-osfhandle) can fail for any number of reason and the error handling doesn't change whether you know the value or otherwise.

Comment: The [CRT source](https://github.com/ojdkbuild/tools_toolchain_sdk10_1607/blob/master/Source/10.0.14393.0/ucrt/inc/corecrt_internal_lowio.h#L94) is available. It is hard-coded and there does not seem to be any API to obtain the value.

Answer (score 1):

As there is `_setmaxstdio` there is also the function `_getmaxstdio`

See the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getmaxstdio?view=msvc-170

Comment: _setmaxstdio() is for stdio, I am asking about the fd values (integers) from _open(), NOT fopen()!!